# Laravel - Unsupported driver

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I am trying to connect to sql server but I get this error

> ocal.ERROR: Unsupported driver [SqlSrv] {"exception":"[object]
>   (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unsupported driver [SqlSrv] at
>   \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:283)

```
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('GAME_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USER', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASS', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
```

Comment: You need to install the drivers `extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll` `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I'd this problem and took me a while to figure it out. It's and old question, but I'm posting how I solved anyway in a Windows DEV environment:

As stated you need to install the PHP - SQL Server drivers from Microsoft.

Problem is that Laravel (version 8.1 on Windows) do not recognise the drivers: php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll.

From \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:287

```
case 'sqlsrv':
    return new SqlServerConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
```

I had to rename the driver files *php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll* and *php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_64.dll* to *php_sqlsrv.dll* and *php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll* (I used the Thread Safe for x64, rename those appropriate for your installation).

In *php.ini* declared the extensions

```
 extension=pdo_sqlsrv
 extension=sqlsrv
```

And worked like a charm. If somebody knows a proper way to fix this, let me know. TY.